# How to print out elements of vector of object

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to create a quiz bank game. I have a .txt file which stores the information and pushes it back to the vector, but my main problem is how to print out my get methods with this pointer to vector of object.

This is my entire code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class question {
private :
    string ques ;
    string answer;
    int point ;
public :
    question(string ques = "",string answer = "",int point = 0):ques(ques),answer(answer),point(point){}

  virtual string getAnswer () = 0;
  virtual string getQuestion() = 0;
  virtual int getPoint() = 0;
};

class SAquestion : public question {
private :
    string ques ;
    string answer;
    int point ;
public :
 SAquestion(string ques = "",string answer = "",int point = 0):ques(ques),answer(answer),point(point){}
  string getAnswer () {return answer;}
  string getQuestion(){return ques ;}
  int getPoint() {return point ;}
};

class MCquestion : public question {
private :
    string ques ;
    string answer;
    int point ;
public :
 MCquestion(string ques = "",string answer = "",int point = 0):ques(ques),answer(answer),point(point){}
  string getAnswer () {return answer;}
  string getQuestion(){return ques ;}
  int getPoint() {return point ;}
};

class TFquestion : public question {
private :
    string ques ;
    string answer;
    int point ;
public :
 TFquestion(string ques = "",string answer = "",int point = 0):ques(ques),answer(answer),point(point){}
  string getAnswer () {return answer;}
  string getQuestion(){return ques ;}
  int getPoint() {return point ;}
};

void readDataByDelimiter(const char* filename, vector< SAquestion>*SHORTQ) {
    string line;
    ifstream ifs(filename);
    if (ifs.is_open()) {
        cout << "Reading data...\n";
        int c = 0;
        while ( getline (ifs,line) && (*line.c_str() != '\0') )  {
            string delimiter = ",";
            size_t pos = 0;
            string* token = new string[5];
            int f = -1;
            while ((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {
                token[++f] = line.substr(0, pos);
                cout << " " << token[f] << " | " ;
                line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
            }
            token[++f] = line;
            cout << token[f] << endl;       // last item in string
            c++;

            // push to vector (numerical data converted to int)
            SAquestion b(token[1], token[2], atoi(token[3].c_str()));
            SHORTQ->push_back(b);
        }
        cout << c << " row(s) read." << endl << endl;
        ifs.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";
}

    enter code here

int main()
{
    vector<SAquestion> *s = new vector<SAquestion>();
    readDataByDelimiter("SHORQ.txt", s);
cout <<s[0]->getAnswer();

}

 - List item
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating a `vector`?  You don't need to, as C++ is not Java and not C#.  Pass by reference to your methods.

Comment: so what do u suggest me to do ? :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to print a `vector`:

```
void Print_Vector(const std::vector<SAquestion>& v)
{
  std::vector<SAquestion>::const_iter  iter;
  const std::vector<SAquestion>::const_iter end_iter = v.end();
  for (iter = v.begin(); iter != end_iter; ++iter)
  {
    cout << *iter << "\n";
  }
}
```

The above code uses an *iterator* to visit each element in the `vector`.  Since printing does not change the contents of the the `vector`, the `vector` is passed by *constant* reference and *constant* iterators are used.

Note:  This function requires that the `operator <<` be overloaded to print an `SAquestion` item.

Note:  By using *pass by reference*, there is no need to use pointers.

**Edit 1: Overloading `operator<<`**
To print an object, change your perspective and have the object print its members.  One convenient method is to overload `operator>>`:

```
class SAquestion
{
 //...
  public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const SAquestion& saq);
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const SAquestion& saq)
{
  output << "Q: " << saq.ques << "\n";
  output << "A: " << saq.answer << "\n";
  output << "\n";
  return output;
}
```

You don't need to use the `getAnswer()` method because the `friend` keyword allows the `operator<<` function to access the `SAquestion` members directly.

Comment: so if i want for example to get one method like :
s[0].getAnswer() how can i do it with this code and thank you :D

Comment: why don't you use a range based `for`

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf:  I don't use *range based* `for` simply because I work with old compilers and have not got in the habit of using range based `for`. :-(

Comment: aww yes i understand thank you...but last question after i do this for every class how can i call it in main so it can print the methods ?

Comment: Use the `operator<<` to print an instance in whatever function your code is in, including `main`.